# Find orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes non-symmetric matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have this matrix

```
B = {{x,0,0},{y,0,0},{z,0,0}}
```

I want to find orthogonal eigenvectors. The eigenvectors of `B`are

```
P = Transpose[Eigenvectors[B]]
```

The orthogonal eigenvectors should be

```
Q = Orthogonalize[P]
```

When I check the result by calculating

```
Inverse[Q].B.Q
```

I get a matrix with some non-diagonal entries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a misunderstanding of the underlying math.

Comment: In order to retain the diagonalizing property, one can only orthogonalize within eigenspaces, that is, orthogonalize eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue.